# How to solve php can not run?

Tags: php

I just installed php7.0 but could not be seen on my browser when I access via

localhost/info.php

when I have a file in /var/www/html/info.php

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

please help how to solve the problem ?

Comment: make sure your webserver has been on

Comment: I've tried to restrat systemctl apache2

Comment: you need to set environment variables. check on net you will get lot of solution

Comment: how about echoing something? ex: echo "test";

Comment: @FahrudinYuniwinanto still not succeeded

Comment: I have found a similar question to your issue, maybe you should take a look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760907/upgrade-to-16-04-php7-not-working-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache2 conf file. It could be in /etc/httpd/conf or /etc/apache2/conf or similiar like that.

In there there should be a path in directory tag. If it is true but still dont work add these to end of your conf file

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

# uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
# or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
# <Directory /var/www/project>
#     Options FollowSymlinks
# </Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/custom_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/custom_access.log combined
```

Comment: By the way you dont need to add ifmodule part.

Comment: the way you mentioned do not succeed

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try "localhost/html/info.php" instead of "localhost/info.php" since you need to specify the path inside the www folder correctly in the url so that the file can be found.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with ssh?
 try php -v in the terminal.

Comment: no, PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

Comment: just trying to see weather the server is running, and thanks for the down vote (y)